# Honda Jazz 51 Electronics Won't Come On

Tags: honda, electrical, jazz

my wife's car's electronics are not working (no central locking, no lights on the dash - nothing). I have tried charging the battery and jump starting the car but no luck. Could a bad fuse stop all of the electronics from working or is it something else ?

Comment: No, not usually ... though a fusible link might be a culprit, but that is an outside chance. Also, that would not indicate why you cannot put jumpers on it to get it going, unless the jumper cables you are trying to use do not have the load capacity to do the work.

Comment: Thanks Paulster the jump leads I have are 400amp and say they are recommended for vehicles up to 2500cc .... Any ideas what else it could be ??

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking an issue with the battery cables.  Likely the ground cable.  Follow it and see if it breaks anywhere.

Get a multimeter.  Measure the voltage between the battery terminals, then between an unpainted part of the body or the engine and the positive terminal.  If the voltage is about the same, your ground is good.  If the voltage is 0, you have a bad ground.  If your ground is good, you will need to follow the positive until you find a break.